# OnclickListner for fragement and activity in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I have a scenario like I have a created a Main Activity and different fragments. MainActivity I am implemented the bottom navigation bar it contains different tabs

1.Task
2.Account
3.Contact

For the above have created the different fragments above tabs we have a common button called '+'.

Now My problem is that if i opened the account fragment want to display the fragment details .In that account tab has common '+' button for all .If I click on + button want to create a new account fragment.

How to resolve it.

MainActivity:

```
 public void initBottomNavigationItems() {


        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {


                Fragment fragment;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.task:
                        toolbar.setTitle("Task");
                        fragment = new TaskFragement();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.account:
                        toolbar.setTitle("Account");
                            fragment = new AccountFragement();
                            loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.contact:
                        toolbar.setTitle("Contact");
                        fragment = new ContactFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.opportunity:
                        toolbar.setTitle("Opportunity");
                        fragment = new OpportuntityFragement();
                        loadFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

If click on account tab it will move to the account fragment .In the same way want if i click on fab button want to replace account fragment with create fragment .But my fab button is in activity_main not in account fragement.

AccountFragement:

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_account.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/White">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/slivergray"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/White">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/appImage"
                    android:layout_width="72dp"
                    android:layout_height="72dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/headingText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
                    android:paddingLeft="16sp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Apollo Hospital"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subHeaderText"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/headingText"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:text="Hospital"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subHeadingText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/subHeaderText"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appImage"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:lines="5"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:text="stories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detailstories_detail"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewOptions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:text="&#8942;"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                    />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_below="@id/subHeadingText">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="209dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/gray"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"></ImageView>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/action1"
                            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Action 1"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="right">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"></ImageView>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/action2"
                            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Action 2"
                            android:textColor="@color/gray"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    </LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use break in switch

Comment: Not clear what you want.. But I guess you want to create multiple fragment on button click. Let me clear first

Comment: " new account fragment." means You want to create new fragment other than ```TaskFragement``` , ```AccountFragement``` , ```ContactFragment```, ```OpportuntityFragement``` ?

Comment: @Afsaredrisy No I will replace accountfragement with otherfargement

Comment: @IamAjijul account i don't have + button .button was available in activity_main

Comment: @Rasel see my edited code

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to call your activity method from fragment.(from a + button in fragment).
Then you can use an `interface` in your fragment to get callback in activity.

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    OnFabClickListener listener;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnFabClickListener{
        public void onCreateNewAccount();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);   

        try {
            listener= (OnFabClickListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFabClickListener");
        }
    }
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onCreateNewAccount();
        }
    });
}

    ...
}
```

Then in your activity implement the interface this way.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFabClickListener
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .....
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateNewAccount() {
        //Add your new account creation code here like loadFragment
    }
}
```

Comment: fab this one where it will come it is in activtiy not in fragement

Comment: then why just you are not calling loadFragment from fab click listener creating new detail fragment or anther activity?